# Creating a templated method of a class in STL style

Tags: c++, stl

Alright, so we know functions in the STL like

```
std::fill(boolContainer.begin(), boolContainer.end(), false);
```

I'm working on a class with a method which also works on a container, and I've realized that I just as well might template it like in the example above The non-templated version is like this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    // ...
    int containerMethod(std::vector<int> &v);
    // ...  
private:
    // ...
};
```

And I'm aiming to change it into:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    // ...
    template <class InputIterator>
    int containerMethod(const InputIterator &begin, const InputIterator &end);
    // ...  
private:
    // ...
};
```

However I'm having trouble working out the details for the implementation:

```
template <class Iter> int SomeClass::containerMethod
(const Iter &begin, const Iter&end) {
    // Here I need to instantiate an iterator for the container.
    Iter iter;
    for (iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter) {
        // This does not seem to work.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is how does one correctly instantiate a templated iterator, based on the templated parameters of a method? Note that I only need an input iterator.

Comment: How it doesn't work? Compiler error, crash, something else?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/NSL6T).

Comment: It is also common in the standard library to pass iterators by value since they are usually very lightweight objects and you often need a copy of them anyways (as you do in this example with `begin`).

Comment: We seem to get this question every 2-3 days, if I had a pound for every time this pops up....

Comment: @DavidBrown you're right, good insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test case is incomplete, so I have to consult my crystal ball.

You have placed your template definition in a source code file, when it should have been in a header file.

See: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid... That was actually the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Where can I find a crystal ball like yours? It's been extremely accurate lately.